# Interpretation of the surface integral in the general solution for poisson‘s equation with dirichlet BC

Tags: electrostatics, greens-functions

If we are given $\Delta \Phi(x)=-\frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon_0}, x \in V$ and $\Phi(x)=\omega(x), x \in \partial V$, we can find a solution to $\Phi(x)$ on $V$ using Green‘s function:

$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_V G(x,y)\rho(y)d^3y-\oint_{\partial V}\vec{n}\cdot \vec{\nabla_y}G(x,y)\omega(y) d^2y$

With $\Delta_yG(x,y)=-\delta(x-y), \quad x,y\in V, \\ G(x,y)=0,    \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad y \in \partial V$

I hope this is correct thus far.

I think I understand the physical interpretation of the first integral. If $V=\mathbb{R}^3, \omega(x)=0$, then $G$ is the potential of a point charge at y, then we convolve this potential with $\rho$ to get the total potential of the charge distribution. If $V$ is bounded but $\omega$ is still $0$, we are not only convolving the potential of a point charge at $x$ with $\rho$ but also it‘s „image charge“ somewhere in the complement of $V$. Where this image charge is, i.e. finding G, has to be done case by case, depending on $V$.

But what if now $\omega(x) \neq 0$ then, to my understanding, G doesn‘t change. It is still (for a chosen $y$) the potential of these two charges. But now we have to consider the surface integral over $\partial V$. It looks to me as if we were subtracting the convolution of the normal component of the electric field caused by these two charges with the potential at the boundary, but why does that make sense? What even is potential times electric field?

Comment: $G$ has dimension 1/length, its gradient has 1/length^2. So it's not exactly potential times electric field... Good question btw. Drop the first term by choosing $\rho=0$ and we're left with the potential caused by the given potential on the boundary, which ultimately is given by some surface charge distribution, at least that's my physical understanding of the situation. And you're right, $\omega \neq 0$ has no influence on $G$, $G$ only depends on the domain geometry.

Comment: This does not look right. Check out the formula 2.24 in document https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/EM-913/section2-Electrostatics.pdf

Comment: Also, why are you assuming $G = 0$ on the boundary?

Comment: What I wrote down is (up to a few constants that depend on the definition of G) exactly formula 2.30 and 2.29 in the document from your link:) Formula 2.24 is more general, what I wrote down only holds for dirichlet BC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113215/physical-interpretation-of-greens-theorem-with-dirichlet-boundary-condition?rq=1